# Usage of "qualifications" and "hobbies"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

When we enquire someone about one's **qualifications** and **hobbies**. Are the following questions correct and if so, can you please give justification.

1. What are your qualifications?

or

2. What is your qualifications?

Please also clarify how to inquire about *hobbies*

Answer (score 1):

Both "qualifications" and "hobbies" are plural. Use "are" rather than "is".

- What are your qualifications?
- What are your hobbies?
- What is your favorite hobby? (some regions spell as "favourite")
- What is your most important qualification?

Comment: Not everyone has a hobby or hobbies; it would be better to ask "Do you have any hobbies?"